# Density estimation with scaled sinc-like kernels

Tags: estimation, kernel-smoothing, interpolation

Given data points $x_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with function values $f_i$,
one can estimate the function at a given $x$ by
$\ \ \ \  \text{f}_{est}( x ) = \frac {\sum { w_i f_i }} {\sum { w_i }}$
with $w_i = k( |x - x_i| )$.
Here $k$() is a kernel function, often Gaussian.
See also [Radial basis function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function).

Consider this variant:
a) make f$_{est}$() scale-free,
the same for $x_i$ at distances 1, 2, 3 $\dots$ as at 10, 20 30 $\dots$,
by taking some number Nnear of the points near $x$
and scaling these Nnear distances by their average $Dav$:
$\ \ \ \  wscaled_i = k( \frac {|x - x_i|} { Dav } )$

b) use the Catmull-Rom a.k.a. C-R spline kernel:

[image]

The C-R spline is widely used in signal and image processing
because it approximates the sinc kernel, which reconstructs band-limited signals
on uniform grids perfectly.
(For scattered / non-uniform points, I have no idea.)
As you see, C-R is 0 at 1, negative from 1 to 2, then 0 beyond 2.
Now if the scaled distances $\frac {|x - x_i|} {Dav}$ are all 1,
$\sum {wscaled_i}$ will be 0; hmm.
Even if they're all near 1, e.g. $\sim \mathcal{N}(1, \text{small}\ \sigma)$,
that's not so hot either.

Do scaled sinc-like kernels make sense for density estimation ?
Has anyone used them in practice ?

(Added):
[Inverse distance weighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting)
is also scale-free, property a) above.
Fwiw, changing the $\tfrac{1}{distance}$ kernel in
[IDW with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104781/inverse-distance-weighted-idw-interpolation-with-python)
to the M-N spline kernel makes not much of a difference there.

Answer (score 3):

There has been lots of work regarding the use of sinus cardinal function as a kernel for density estimation. Most of the work involving sinc kernels is actually for density deconvolution in error-in-variable models because the Fourier transform has a compact support and because it enjoys nice computational properties. In terms of implementations there is an implementation in R called 'deamer' and you may also consider a Matlab package EstimHidden by yves rozenholc.

Comment: interesting, +1. Can you suggest an introduction t deconvolution methods ? Would you have any comments on fitting smooth f to not much data in 5d or so ?